# melt data.table produces data.frame in some cases

Tags: r, data.table

It seems as if some libraries disable data.table melt. I am not sure whether this is a bug or whether I am doing something wrong. By trial and error I have found GGally as one of the "offending" libraries.

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
library(GGally)

dt = data.table(mtcars, keep.rownames = T)
m = melt(dt, id.var = "rn")
str(m)
> 'data.frame': 352 obs. of  3 variables
```

commenting out library(GGally) gives:

```
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    352 obs. of  3 variables
```

Details:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] GGally_0.4.5     reshape_0.8.4    plyr_1.8         ggplot2_0.9.3.1  reshape2_1.2.2   data.table_1.9.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-4   dichromat_2.0-0    digest_0.6.4       grid_3.1.0         gtable_0.1.2       labeling_0.2       MASS_7.3-31       
 [8] munsell_0.4.2      proto_0.3-10       RColorBrewer_1.0-5 scales_0.2.3       stringr_0.6.2      tools_3.1.0
```

Comment: What package versions are you using? I get a `data.table` even with `library(GGally)` intact.

Comment: If you could edit the output of `sessionInfo()` into your question, that might be helpful.

Comment: you're absolutely right. sessionInfo added.

Comment: Could you try updating `reshape` (0.8.5 is latest) and `reshape2` (1.4 is latest)? I remember the issue in the past due to `reshape` masking the other melt methods..

Comment: done. GGally_0.4.5, reshape_0.8.5,ggplot2_0.9.3.1, reshape2_1.4, data.table_1.9.2. still produces a data.frame.

Comment: Also, update GGally to 0.4.6 and see if it persists. From the `NEWS`, it *Moved ggplot2 and reshape into Imports and not Depends*. When you've done that, obviously restart R and see if the problem persists.

Comment: updating GGally solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updating GGally solved the problem.

"From the NEWS, it [GGally] Moved ggplot2 and reshape into Imports and not Depends" [Ananda Mahto]